# Why i am not getting the decimal number as output? The code is explained with the help of comments

Tags: arduino-ide

```
// Defined three array arr0,arr1,arr2
int arr0[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int arr1[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int arr2[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

//cord function takes binary number array as input and returns decimal 
//number to a single variable as output
int cord(int a[]) {
  int v = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    int p = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
      p = p * 2;
    }
    v = v + a[i] * p;
  }
  return v;
}

//function bcord takes input row & col and updates the value in arr0,arr1,arr2 to 1 wherever
// there is some value in the row and column coordinate Eg.2,0 will make 2nd index of arr0
// to 1 or 2,1 will make 2nd index of arr1 to 1
int bcord(int row[], int col[])
{

  int n = sizeof(col) / sizeof(col[0]);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    int j;
    if (col[i] == 2)
    {
      j = row[i];
      arr2[j] = 1;
    }
    if (col[i] == 1)
    {
      j = row[i];
      arr1[j] = 1;
    }
    if (col[i] == 0)
    {
      j = row[i];
      arr0[j] = 1;
    }
  }
  int led0 = cord(arr0);
  Serial.print(led0);
  int led1 = cord(arr1);
  Serial.println(led1);
  int led2 = cord(arr2);
  Serial.println(led2);
  return 0;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int row[] = {0, 0, 2, 2, 1};
  int col[] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1};
  bcord(row, col);
}

void loop() {}
// Output expected is decimal numbers which are stored in led0, led1 and led2 on the serial
// monitor
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: your code is improperly formatted ... code that should be indented, isn't indented ... code that should not be indented, is indented ... it's a mess

Comment: I just used the autoindent function of the Arduino IDE. You should make more use of it, because correct indenting comes in very handy to find certain syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you jsotola, Chrisl & Edgar! But i get 57 and then 0 in next line as output. How can i get the decimal values stored in led0, led1 and led2?

Comment: “570” is correct: `led0` is 5, `led1` is 7 and `led2` is 0.

Comment: Thank you Edgar, i totally missed that!

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you cannot pass an array as a parameter to a function. When you
write the function prototype

```cpp
int bcord(int row[], int col[], int n)
```

the compiler considers it a synonym of:

```cpp
int bcord(int *row, int *col, int n)
```

In other words, both `row` and `col` are pointers, not arrays.

When you call the function like this:

```cpp
bcord(row, col);
```

the compiler implicitly converts the call into this:

```cpp
bcord(&row[0], &col[0]);
```

In other words, you are really passing pointers to the first element of
each array. This is a standard language behavior called “decay to
pointer”.

When I compile your code with warnings enabled, I get the following:

```
In function 'int bcord(int*, int*)':
warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'col'
will return size of 'int*' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
   int n = sizeof(col) / sizeof(col[0]);
                     ^
arr-ind.ino:31:30: note: declared here
 int bcord(int row[], int col[])
                              ^
```

Thus the compiler is telling you what is wrong. The variable `n` is not
what you expect.

The standard solution is to pass the size of the array from the caller:
move the definition of `n` to `setup()`, define `bcord()` as:

```cpp
int bcord(int row[], int col[], int n)
```

and call it as

```cpp
bcord(row, col, n);
```